# Casting normal pointer to std::shared_ptr doesn't seem to work

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, c++11, shared-ptr

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
std::map <const std::string, std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture> > resources;
sf::Texture tempResource;
tempResource.loadFromFile("1.PNG");

resources.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>("1", std::dynamic_pointer_cast<sf::Texture>( new sf::Texture(tempResource) ) ) );

return 0;
}
```

(that new call uses copy constructor)

Without casting (just calling new inside insert function) it didn't work. So i used shared_ptr casting to do it, however it doesn't work. The error:
**error: no matching function for call to ‘dynamic_pointer_cast(sf::Texture*)’**

What's wrong here, how can I make it to work? I'm new to shared_ptrs and I just can't solve it myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is creating a `shared_ptr` from formerly unmanaged memory. `dynamic_pointer_cast` isn't the tool for the job. Instead this should work:

```
resources.insert(std::pair<const std::string, std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>>("1", std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>(new sf::Texture(tempResource)));
//or:
resources.insert(std::make_pair("1", std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>(new sf::Texture(tempResource)));
```

However constructing a `shared_ptr` from newly allocated memory is somewhat wasterful. since this does two allocations (one for the memory and one for the internal data of the `shared_ptr`). If you use `std::make_shared(tempResource)` those two allocations can be combined into one for higher efficiency.

C++11 would also allow `resources.emplace("1", std::make_shared(tempResource)` for inplace construction of the pair, but last time I checked the compiler support for that was somewhat lacking.

As a side note: if you don't need `tempResource` anymore, you might want to consider moving (instead of copying it into the datastructure by using `std::move(tempResource)` instead of `tempResource` for constructiong the newly allocated object. Depending on the implementation of `sf::texture` this might (or might not) be more efficient. If the object isn't truely move-constructible (so move-construction is basically the same as a copy), you might want to constructing the `Texture` directly into a `shared_ptr` and calling load on that one:

```
auto tempResource = std::make_shared<sf::Texture>();
tempResource->loadFromFile("1.PNG");
resources.emplace("1",std::move(tempResource));//or insert if emplace isn't availible
```

Comment: @user1873947: If it solves your problem, you might want to consider accepting either Kerrek's or my answer to show that the problem is solved. Of course upvoting an answer is also a nice way to show gratitude ;)

Comment: I can't vote because of my low rep... Both answers are great but I will choose yours because you have lower rep.

Answer (score 0):

You should say:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<sf::Texture>> resources;
      // ^^^ "const" is redundant

// ...

resources.insert(std::make_pair("1", std::make_shared<sf::Texture>(tempResource)));
```

If your platform supports it, you can even say:

```
resources.emplace("1", std::make_shared<sf::Texture>(tempResource));
```

Or:

```
resources.emplace("1", new sf::Texture(tempResource));
```

But that's not as good as `make_shared`, which is more efficient, and it violates the rule-of-good-taste to never use `new`. Either way, the point of `emplace` is that it allows explicit constructors, unlike `insert`.

---

Even even better is this, not using a temporary at all:

```
resources.emplace("1", std::make_shared<sf::Texture>()).second->loadFromFile("1.PNG");
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems the best way, but... g++ will support emplace since 4.8... meh... Well, I'll do it insert way for now and make the comment to update it to emplace when 4.8 is released.

Comment: @user1873947: Sure, but scrap that temporary in any case and go with the final solution (you can do something similar with `insert`).

Comment: sure, but I need to it in resManager::add function, so I need to make a design that it won't create 2 instances of the same thing. However, it should be rather easy.

Comment: I mean I want a easier way of calling add function, without typing std::make_shared<sf::Texture>()).second->loadFromFile("1.PNG") as argument

Comment: @user1873947: Your finger-laziness doesn't matter. `make_shared` is more efficient than `new` and you should prefer that.